# double enter needed. why?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm facing a problem with a need to double "enter" in order for the program to proceed, can someone enlighten me?

```
public void run() {
    try {
        out.write("Enter message to encrypt: \n");
        out.flush();

        while (true) {

            entry = in.readLine();
            result = caesarCipher(entry);

            out.write("The encrypted message is " + result);
            out.write("\tType q to end else type another message to encrypt");
            out.flush();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

this is over at the client side

```
public EncryptClient() throws IOException {
    Socket cSock = new Socket("LocalHost", portNumber);
    Reader iRead = new InputStreamReader(cSock.getInputStream());
    input = new BufferedReader(iRead);

    userTerminal = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    output = new OutputStreamWriter(cSock.getOutputStream());

    while (true) {
        String line = input.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        line = userTerminal.readLine();

        if (line.equals("q")) {
            break;
        }
        output.write(line + "\n");
        output.flush();
    }
}
```

when my client class is connect to the server class, i will need to enter a message for encryption, but a double enter is needed to show the result. can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

ReadLine will halt the control of flow.

In your code, they were two readLine
`.readLine();` // (line string is overrided twice)duplicated. Remove it. You will be fine.